# Converting portions of an int array into integers?

Tags: java, arrays, int

I'm trying to convert a message, say in the form of `"22 12 20 28"` into an array, say `[22, 12, 20, 28]` then into individual integers, say 22, 12, 20, then 28. I have code that should work, but for some reason it doesn't.

```
public class Decrypt {
    private String myMessage;
    private String e = "2718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627724076630353547594571382178525166427427466391932003059921817413596629043572900334295260595630738132328627943490763233829880753195251019011573834187930702154089149934884167509244761460668082264800168477411853742345442437107539077744992069551702761838606261331384583000752044933826560297606737113200709328709127443747047230696977209310141692836819025515108657463772111252389784425056953696770785449969967946864454905987931636889230098793127736178215424999229576351482208269895193668033182528869398496465105820939239829488793320362509443117301238197068416140397019837679320683282376464804295311802328782509819455815301756717361332069811250996181881593041690351598888519345807273866738589422879228499892086805825749279610484198444363463244968487560233624827041978623209002160990235304369941849146314093431738143640546253152096183690888707016768396424378140592714563549061303107208510383750510115747704171898610687396965521267154688957035035402123407849819334321068170121005627880235193033224745015853904730419957777093503660416997329725088687696640355570716226844716256079882651787134195124665201030592123667719432527867539855894489697096409754591856956380236370162112047742722836489613422516445078182442352948636372141740238893441247963574370263755294448337";
    private int character;
    private int myInteger;
    private int eInteger;
    private String decryptedMessage = "";

    public Decrypt(String myMessage){
        this.myMessage = myMessage;
    }

    public String Decryption(){         
        String[] splitMessage = myMessage.split(" ");
        int[] numbers = new int[splitMessage.length];
        String[] eMessage = e.split("");
        int[] eNumbers = new int[eMessage.length];

        for (int i=0; i<myMessage.length(); i++){
            eInteger = eNumbers[i];
            myInteger = numbers[i];
            System.out.println(eInteger + " " + myInteger);
            character = myInteger - eInteger;
            String stringCharacter = Integer.toString(character);
            decryptedMessage = decryptedMessage + " " + stringCharacter;
            System.out.println(i);

        }
        return decryptedMessage;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Message: " + Decryption();
    }    
}
```

I think the problem is in:

```
for (int i=0; i<myMessage.length(); i++){
    eInteger = eNumbers[i];
    myInteger = numbers[i];
    System.out.println(eInteger + " " + myInteger);
    character = myInteger - eInteger;
    String stringCharacter = Integer.toString(character);
    decryptedMessage = decryptedMessage + " " + stringCharacter;
    System.out.println(i);    
}
```

But I have no idea what is wrong with it. I don't need help with doing it any easier way, I just want to know why it's not returning what I want it to. It's just returning 0's.

Comment: You don't put anything in `numbers` or `eNumbers`, therefore they are 0. One would assume something ought to go in them but you didn't say what so I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: But I put i in them? It's supposed to convert eNumbers[0] to an int, then eNumbers[1] to an int, and so on.

Comment: *"But I put i in them?"* You didn't put anything in them. *"It's supposed to convert eNumbers[0] to an int, then eNumbers[1] to an int, and so on."* Array elements in an `int[]` are already `int`... There is some fundamental step that you are missing and we really can't help you because we don't know how your program is supposed to work either. If this is homework you should review the text for the assignment and ask the instructor if it's unclear.

Answer (score 0):

for one,

```
      int[] numbers = new int[splitMessage.length];
```

doesn't automagically make an array assigned with all the strings converted to an int. You have to do that explicitly.

Comment: How do I do that explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

You have not written any code that converts the individual strings into integers. This would normally be done with something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitMessage[i]);
}
```

If you are using Java 8 you could also use:

```
int[] numbers = Arrays.stream(splitMessage)
    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```